# How to stop windows service as administrator in python?

Tags: python, windows, service, access-denied, administrator

I already tried a few ways but none of them worked.

```
os.system('net stop service_name')
```

which returns "System error 5 has occurred. Access denied.

```
os.system('runas /user:Administrator net stop service_name')
```

no errors, but nothing happened

```
subprocess.Popen(
    ['runas', '/user:Administrator', 'net stop service_name'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE
)
process.stdin.write(b'admin_password_here')
```

again nothing happened

```
win32serviceutil.StopService(service_name)
```

and few more ways

Comment: win32serviceutil.StopService works for me. Of course, the process must be run from the administrator.

Answer (score 0):

try add `noprofile`:

```
import os
service_name = ''
action = "stop"
os.system(f'runas /noprofile /user:administrator "net {action} '{service_name}'"')
```

Comment: Already tried. It asked me for a password. 
`Enter the password for administrator: `

Comment: and you need to enter the password @James

Comment: don't know how or I'm doing it wrong because nothing happened. just no error for access denied.

what's the proper way of doing it?

Let me tell you the whole case. I need to stop and start services on remote machine. I can connect, install the current program them do some other things and in the end I need to stop/start a service but I can't.

I guess I'm just stupid and can't execute locally 5 lines of good to stop any service as admin...